# Laravel update a null value or ignore, or insert if reference key don't exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about `insertOrIgnore` method, in the last time I used `upsert` method to update or create a new row on my database structured like this:

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | "foo" | "bar" |
| 4 | null | "vel" |

With `upsert`, I'm able to update the name with `id = 4`, but doing something like this:

```php
DB::table('funnypeople')->insertOrIgnore(
  ['id' => 4, 'name' => "lara"]
);
```

He don't change the name from `null` to `"lara"`

There's something similar to update a value if is `null` but not update if is already set?

Other case, if I would like to add id if not exist and save all the value

```php
DB::table('funnypeople')->insertOrIgnore(
  [
   'id' => 4, 'name' => "lara",
   'id' => 6, 'name' => "fancy", 'surname' => 'people'
]);
```

The resulting table should be:

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | "foo" | "bar" |
| 4 | "lara" | "vel" |
| 6 | "fancy" | "people" |

I tried olso to pass the reference column like in upsert but it add only the new row on the table:

```php
DB::table('funnypeople')->insertOrIgnore(
  [
   'id' => 4, 'name' => "lara",
   'id' => 6, 'name' => "fancy", 'surname' => 'people'
],'id');
```

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | "foo" | "bar" |
| 4 | null | "vel" |
| 6 | "fancy" | "people" |

Comment: @TimLewis sorry, I edit my question, anyway I pass an array there

Comment: Figured that was the case; your code wouldn't have run otherwise  Anyway, looking at the docs: "The `insertOrIgnore` method will ignore errors while inserting records into the database"; this doesn't seem to do an `upsert()`, so it won't update `null => 'lara'` for `id: 4`.

Comment: Re: your update; `insertOrIgnore()` doesn't take a 2nd argument, only the `[]` of values being saved: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertOrIgnore. Honestly, just use `upsert()` or other methods; you're trying to make `insertOrIgnore()` do something that it is not programmed to do.

Comment: @TimLewis i know, but sometime I need just to keep "new" values and ignore the already existing ones

Comment: Then you'll need to handle that on your own with other existing methods. Also, typically, you don't manually insert `id` values; it's generally an auto-incrementing column. Is that not the case with your database table?

Answer (score 0):

From laravel docs:

> **The insertOrIgnore method will ignore errors while inserting** records
> into the database:

```
DB::table('users')->insertOrIgnore([
    ['id' => 1, 'email' => 'sisko@example.com'],
    ['id' => 2, 'email' => 'archer@example.com'],
]);
```

> **insertOrIgnore will ignore duplicate records and also may ignore other types of errors** depending on the database engine. For example, insertOrIgnore will bypass MySQL's strict mode.

for insert or update you need this:

> Occasionally, you may need to update an existing model or create a new model if no matching model exists. Like the firstOrCreate method, the updateOrCreate method persists the model, so there's no need to manually call the save method.

```
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

more info in [official Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts)

In your code example you are using `insertOrIgnore` instead of `upsert`. insertOrIgnore don´t update just insert ignoring errors, in you case can´t insert the id 4 because primary key fails but was ignored and continue to insert ID 6

```
DB::table('funnypeople')->insertOrIgnore(
  [
   'id' => 4, 'name' => "lara", //Fail because PK exist in DB
   'id' => 6, 'name' => "fancy", 'surname' => 'people' //Continue inserting this
]);
```

Comment: Yes, I know...so which method should I use???

Comment: Use updateOrCreate, is that you need

Comment: no. cause I don't wanna update an existing value..if I need I use upsert

Comment: Oh sorry then, then you can use this: 
$toRemove = DB::table('funnypeople')->select()->whereIn('id', arrayOfIdsToInsert)->get();

remove all models from your first array and do a insert. At least u need clean your data before insert

Comment: In the end I did it in another way, using cte I found all the missing data, with a foreach I delete from original array all the data i don't need and then an upsert

Comment: Have no sense do a upsert when you dont need it. Use a insert for that, no chance to update anything because you are deleting the data you don´t need.